# Sort unanswered questions by tag

Tags: support, tags, statistics, questions

Please excuse my mo.meta ignorance.

Is it possible to view the list of percentage of unanswered questions, sorted by tag? (This is somewhat ill-posed because many questions have multiple tags, but that should not matter too much).

My motivation for this is plain curiosity: I wanted to see which particular tag (or subject category) has the highest percentage of unanswered questions, and which one the highest percentage of answered questions.

Based on the hint given by Martin, here is the data explorer link that does the job:

[Data explorer sort by unanswered tag query](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/147314/unanswered-questions-by-tag)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you Google for [unanswered tag site:data.stackexchange.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=unanswered+tag+site:data.stackexchange.com) you can find some already existing Data Explorer queries for this. For example:

- [Unanswered Questions by Tag](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/42823/unanswered-questions-by-tag): Shows the number of unanswered questions by tag for the most popular tags. The same query was used in a [similar question on meta.math.SE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23148/best-and-worst-tags-for-answered-rate).
- [Unanswered Questions by Tag](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/50761/unanswered-questions-by-tag): Shows all tags with at least 3000 questions, their total questions and of those, how many are unanswered.
- [Unanswered Questions by Tag with at least 100 questions](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/77412/unanswered-questions-by-tag-with-at-least-100-questions)
- [Unanswered Questions by Tag](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/50761/unanswered-questions-by-tag): Shows all tags with at least 3000 questions, their total questions and of those, how many are unanswered.

You can probably find more similar queries or modify the above queries for your purposes.

You should be aware that the notion of *[unanswered question](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/tags/unanswered-questions/info)* has some ambiguity to it. On SE network usually a question is considered unanswered even if it has some answers, but none of them is upvoted or accepted, see [here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/ok-now-define-answered/). (For example, the questions on the [unanswered tab](https://mathoverflow.net/questions?sort=unanswered) or the questions that are bumped by the [Community User](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/who-is-the-community-user) are questions fulfilling these criteria.)

Comment: Per [OP's request](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1157/sort-unanswered-questions-by-tag/1163#comment5282_1158), I have expanded my comment to an answer.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this using a [data explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/queries) query or just using a plain search for `[tag] answers:0`. ([For example](https://mathoverflow.net/search?q=%5Blo.logic%5D+answers%3A0).)

Comment: I guess, the latter does not do what I want (because I want a sorted list by which tag has the least answered questions), but the former solution via the data explorer might work out---provided I construct the correct query! thanks.

Comment: What is one's "`UserId`" in the context of data-explorer queries, may I ask?

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke: Yours is 6094

Comment: @Suvrit If you Google for [unanswered tag site:data.stackexchange.com](http://www.google.com/search?q=unanswered+tag+site:data.stackexchange.com) you can find some queries already existing for this.

Comment: @Martin: thanks! exactly what I needed. You may wish to make your comment an answer. I copied that sql query and executed it already thanks!